# Create a real time graph with Excel (2016)

Tags: excel, arduino

I make a project with an Arduino nano 33 BLE sense. This project is a boxing captor which is on a punching bag and use the accelerometer of the arduino in order to deduce the power of the boxer.
I use PLX-DAQ and its works but i want to plot the graph while the Arduino is measuring the acceleration (when i move the card).
But when i launch PLX-DAQ i just have the dat in real time in the columns but nothing on the graph..
I try some things but i did'nt manage to have a graph plot in live.

[excel after measuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb7sr.png)

How can I do that ?

thanks

Comment: your screenshot is completely useless due to its low resolution.  provide your code, details on your configuration...

Comment: Learn how to use [Arduion Serial Plotter](https://learn.adafruit.com/experimenters-guide-for-metro/circ08-using%20the%20arduino%20serial%20plotter).